# Regularized linear regression fails to predict my data

Tags: regression, lasso, glmnet

I an relatively new to machine learning and wonder about the following:
I have numeric input with the number of variables close to the number of observations, and numeric outputs. Almost all input and output variables seem to be normally distributed.

To avoid over-fitting I used cross validated Lasso / Ridge / Elastic net regression (various alphas and Lambdas), but didn't manage to bring the MSE to be more than slightly lower than the variance of the output.

Does this simply mean that the relations, if exist at all, are nonlinear? If so, and since I have no knowledge about the nature of this non linearity, do I have other options beside applying neural networks?

Comment: What kind of data is it? Do you have any idea what kind of relation might hold between the input and output? Coudl you show us a plot of the data?

Comment: I agree with @dimpol. I would also add that given the OP's description, the first word in the title, "Regularized", is perhaps extraneous?